# Getting an empty object in Axios Get Request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, object, axios, backend

I am trying to set up a get route using axios. I am using React. I am trying to get the state of user.

user.user logs:

```
{_id: '62c5bdda933b818e12bef350', username: 'JordanF', Profiles: Array(9), createdAt: '2022-07-06T16:52:42.396Z', updatedAt: '2022-07-09T19:24:10.523Z', …}
```

I am trying to display username on my page. But at the moment I can't even log the username to my backend, so won't be able to search my db.

**Profile.jsx**

```
 function getUser(data) {
  console.log(data)
  axios({
      url: `http://localhost:3000/profiles`,
      method: "GET",
      data: data
  })
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
  }

useEffect(() => {
    setProfileList(profiles)
    getUser(user.user)
  },[]);
```

Data logs the data in the front end that I would like to get in the backend

**BackEnd Controller**
I have tried a lot of different syntax for this, this is my most recent. In the backend temrinal my console.log hits, and req.body returns an empty object.

```
async function getUser(req,res){
console.log('getUser hit')
function log(){
    console.log(req.body)
    return req.body
}
await log()
```

}

Comment: you need a parser installed for a node/express app to read body payloads in the request.

Comment: Usually you would never send data on a GET request. Axios may not even allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup! I was being silly. GET requests are only really concerned with params. I changed my route, so that the User's ID was in the URL path, and used req.params.id and everything worked out!